# How to configure nginx redirection

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, return, webserver, url-rewrite-module

I have configured my domain in Nginx web server and now I want to redirect all request to the main domain.

For example: 1) http://www.example.com/blogs/articles should be redirected to http://www.example.com

2) http://www.example.com/wp/history should be redirected to http://www.example.com/products/file

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that it is a bad practice. Instead, you should send all requests to a PHP-file (or a peer) and redirect from there.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly you wish to do.
I mean regularity of your redirections is not clear.

Here is an article. Maybe it would be helpful.
**https://bjornjohansen.no/nginx-redirect**

**It's better to not have a lot of single redirections in server configs because it can be very complicated and inflexible.**

Meanwhile, the "stupid" way to do it:

Using maps

If you have a list of URLs or regular expressions that you want to redirect differently, you ought to look into using a map, which you very well may define in a separate file for your convenience. Just note that the map definition must be outside the server block:

include redirect-map.conf;

```
server {
    […]
    if ( $redirect_uri ) {
        return 301 $redirect_uri;
    }
}
```

The file redirect-map.conf may then look something like this:

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri {
    /about.html          /about-us;
    /customers.html      /our-customers;
    /products.html       /our-products;
}
```

Note the following excerpt from the docs: